# PHP: Cleanly upgrading/replacing PHP from unavailable repository on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 Apache2/PHP/MYSQL server that was using a deprecated version of PHP. I realized this once I tried to install the sqlite3 extension I get an error:

Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources

Research shows me that this is no longer used and instead use ondrej/php instead. This is a production server and I need to figure out steps to replace the PPA with the correct one.

Will I need to uninstall PHP and reinstall using the new packages? If so how should I go about doing this cleanly?

Is there a way to temporarily install sqlite3 without having to change repositories completely (I do not have php-dev installed at the moment either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check if there are any compatibility issues with the version you want to upgrade to (did a quick google to find this: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer). Then, add the repository that contains the version you want, sudo apt-get update and install the version of php you want. To switch the version apache uses, do the following:

```
sudo a2dismod php5 
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: What if I do not have the apache module for php5.6? Whats a good way to install that?

Comment: you can install modules like this: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6

Comment: Can you also install php7 and do the same? I think I've read you should remove php5 before. Do you need if it's true? The process would not be as smooth I suppose.

Comment: Not really sure, but I think it should be the same process unless maybe you are using really old versions of mysql and Apache stuff that may need updating or something.